# Composer not installing

Tags: php, mysql, apache, dll, xampp

I have installed windows 10 on my pc and when I installing composer it shows:

> The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
>   D:\Xampp\php\php.exe

The `php.ini` used by your command-line PHP is: **D:\Xampp\php\php.ini**

A setting in your `php.ini` could be causing the problem: Either the '**extension_dir**' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:

```
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_bz2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_fileinfo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_gd2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_gettext.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_mbstring.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_exif.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '\xampp\php\ext\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
     in Unknown on line 0
    PHP Warning:  Cannot open '\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini' for reading in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: "Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist." seems like something to check.

Comment: @tadman What i have to do now??

Answer (score 0):

May I know do you run it by administrator powershell during the installation,

if yes please check those extensions whether exist or not,

and does install correctly : 
https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#using-the-installer

```
C:\bin>echo @php "%~dp0composer.phar" %*>composer.bat
```

The @php does it point to your php of xampp? You can check .